# Uniform in zeromq for realtime purpose

Tags: java, c++, c, tcp, zeromq

I need to implement analytics system with server and terminals which in realtime.

I use library ZeroMq (pub|sub mode) to send messages to client (~40bytes).

if I connect with 1 client, messages come with delay (sometime more than 250ms). 
if I connect with 100 clients a lot of clients lose uniformity of delivery (more than 750ms no one message, after that huge scope of data). It is so critical issue for me.

I have to publish to more than 6000 terminals...
Publish every 30ms, it is about 1700bytes to each client in the worst case  (tcp)

Maybe I should use another technology to deliver messages in realtime?

Comment: Multicast is not our way, because our termainals far away from each other. In this case we have to provide a lot of stable channels to terminals

Comment: @Bob could you please add info about O/S, ZeroMQ version and the MCVE code you work with? Also kindly consider a quantitative expression of what fits into a real-time schedule and what does not, StackOverflow people love complex scenarios and strive to help solve well defined issues. **Anyway, welcome to this great community, Bob & do not hesitate to become our actively contributing member.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, Multicast is the way. The primary overriding concern is whether your terminals can join the group you are publishing on - irrespective of how far away they are.

You've not indicated how the terminals connect to your network - (for example vpn over internet, private line whatever..) You asked for a better technology - it's multicast.

Now there are some options if you are going to go down the tcp route:

- Build a load-balacing infrastructure which sits in front of your
  service. Meaning that your terminals don't connect to your
  service, but to a set of load balancers which then connect to your
  service. If you have 10 of these for example, each only has to deal
  with 600 clients. Your problem is much smaller - you can scale this
  way. Don't forget to use asynchronous io.
- Buy better hardware - for example solace or tervela do hardware
  message brokers which can scale to very large numbers concurrent tcp
  connections - but this is not cheap.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, I'm using 0mq for balancing purpose, I can easily implement pub|sub and proxy on it. But I can not understand why it work so ununiform

Comment: At some point each physical write over tcp will take some time (depending on your hardware.) Scale this time up to 6000 clients, the write for the 6000th client will be after the first 5999 writes have taken place (factor in async writes - scaled by number of threads/cpus etc.) - frankly there's no real guarantee as to *when exactly* the data for a particular client is written to the wire..

Comment: ...and you are probably timing from a single timestamp generated for a message (which is replicated) to each client (and unless you have PTP or NTP atleast for time sync - any measurements you do oneway are not very reliable..

Comment: Thanks you @Nim
At this moment, we directly use NIO and after 200-300 clients we spend a lot of time to write to socket, and size of queue with messages is growing up. Our way it's improvements hardware characteristics and make cascade of servers, isn't it? Do we have some possibility to improve and optimize write to NIO socket?

Comment: Are you using netty (or NIO directly?) Can't really say much about the code front without having some idea of what it looks like - may be you can post on codereview to see if there can be some improvements. This kind of scaling doesn't really work well with tcp - like I said, after a point, you have to look at hardware messaging brokers.